# WSO2 Proxy services with RabbitMQ - consumer connection closed on retry on failover

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-es

[2023-10-05 10:46:19,726] ERROR {ForgivingExceptionHandler} - Consumer org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask@7420920b (amq.ctag-8tDUZqiXFr6izWTHTEpr8A) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://xxx@127.0.0.1:5672/,1) threw an exception for channel AMQChannel(amqp://xx@127.0.0.1:5672/,1) java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.handleDelivery(ServiceTaskManager.java:222)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2023-10-05 10:46:19,726]  INFO {ServiceTaskManager} - The connection to the messaging server was shut down. Consumer tag amq.ctag-8tDUZqiXFr6izWTHTEpr8A

Getting above error on proxy services while retry through rabbitmq

Referred document

https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rabbitmq_examples/retry-delay-failed-msgs-rabbitmq/